# Vector potential of axisymmetric electromagnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

Consider an axisymmetric electromagnetic field. Using cylindrical coordinates $(r,\theta, z)$, where the axis of symmetry is the $z$-axis, let the radial component of the vector potential $A$ be $A_r$ and the $z$-axis component be $A_z$.
I want to show proposition that $A_r=0$ and $A_z=0$.
I have tried the following calculations:

$A=A_{x}dx+A_{y}dy+A_{z}dz=A_{r}dr+A_{\theta}d\theta+A_{z}dz$

$dx = \cos\theta dr - r \sin\theta d\theta $
$dy = \sin\theta dr + r \cos\theta d\theta $

Therefore, from these we obtain the following equation:
$A_r = (A_r,A_\theta,A_z)=(A_x \cos\theta + A_y \sin\theta, -A_x r \sin\theta + A_y r \cos\theta, A_z)$

I have no idea how to show $A_r$ and $A_z$ since $E$ and $B$ do not depend on $\theta$.

Comment: Your question appears to be a homework question but have you attempted anything yet?

Comment: This is not homework and I am asking because I ran some calculations and could not understand it.

Comment: I understand this question is not homework but it looks like a homework problem. The solution is for you to edit it to show what results you got when you tried the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I will now add the results of the calculations I have done.

Comment: Vector potential $\mathbf A$ is arbitrary up to a gradient of scalar function. Such gradient can produce non-zero component of $A_r,A_z$. If you want to get unique $\mathbf A$ with those components being zero, you have to specify the exact definition of the vector potential, such as via the Coulomb integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a counterexample of your proposed idea, note that for any $\mathbf{A}$ with $A_r = A_z = 0$ we have
$$
(\nabla \times \vec{A})_\theta = \frac{\partial A_r}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial A_z}{\partial r} = 0.
$$
This means that we cannot find such an $\mathbf{A}$ corresponding to a magnetic field with a non-zero $\theta$-component, such as the field for a long wire.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am convinced.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot show that. Since $$\mathbf {A(r)} = \frac{\mu_o}{4\pi}\int dv' \frac {\mathbf {J(r')}}{\mathbf {|r-r'|}},$$ see, for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_vector_potential). Now if, $\mathbf J = J\hat z$ then $\mathbf A = A \hat z$, as well.

Comment: That equation is only true in the Coulomb gauge, though;  it relies on the fact that $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A} = 0$.  It's not immediately obvious to me that you couldn't find some other gauge in which $A_r$ and/or $A_z$ are zero even if $J_z \neq 0$.  (It does turn out to be impossible — see my answer below — but the argument needs shoring up.)